# thinking objectively vs. functionally

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

As I try to increase my knowledge of functional programming, I'm finding it quite difficult to re-imagine the solutions to problems I've solved in an OOP language in terms of functions, particularly where widgets are involved. Sites like Project Euler and 4Clojure are great for learning core functions and techniques for manipulating primitive data, but what I'd really like is a resource that discusses how to idiomatically translate OOP constructs into FP, with particular attention to identifying when and how to use state. (To use a concrete example, what is the best way to implement a piano keyboard in Clojure?)

Comment: State is just data over time. Can you be more specific in what you are stuck on? As it stands, it is hard to answer this question as it is overly broad.

Comment: I guess I'm confused about how the data should be maintained. A keyboard is presumably a list of closures. Should the functionality of the key (reverse the color when clicked, generate a particular pitch, etc) be fully contained within each closure? Should changes in state instead be produced by an external function?

Comment: Voting to close as "too broad", but you should check out other people's projects for inspiration. For example, @mikera's rouge-like alchemy over at http://clojurefun.wordpress.com/.

Comment: Are you familiar with Clojure's "Time model"? Once you get it, it'll all make sense - in particular, translating OO thinking will be trivial (in fact your programs will be drastically less complex).

Comment: Since you seem interested in Clojure answers (it isn't a "type system" question), I won't post this as an answer, but if you are okay with learning some OCaml and perhaps Haskell, see [my answer regarding modularity](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/200980/how-do-purely-functional-languages-handle-modularity/201018#201018). Comprehensive OCaml books, including the brand new "Real World OCaml", discuss the question of when to use objects.

Comment: Regarding the piano keyboard - check out how pedestal application solves it - essentially by defining an implicit state which only can be changed by well specified messages (keydown, keyup). The state can be stored in anything controllably mutable - an atom for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know two books that might help:

["Functional Programming for the Object-Oriented Programmer"](https://leanpub.com/fp-oo) by Brian Marick.

["Clojure Programming"](http://www.clojurebook.com/) by Chas Emerick, Brian Carper and Chirstophe Grand. Chapter 12 is  about how to "translate" Object-Oriented Design Patterns to Clojure.

Comment: Marick's book looks like what I had in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> what I'd really like is a resource that discusses how to idiomatically translate OOP constructs into FP

Don't. That's a classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I hate analogies but an equivalent in engineering might be to say that you've mastered metalwork and want to learn plastics by recreating the same shapes in plastic. In reality, you never want to translate what you know into what you're learning. What you really want to do is learn how to solve familiar problems using new techniques. Going back to engineering, good plastic designs are not the same shape as good metal designs. In terms of programming, solutions build using one paradigm never translate well to another. You should re-solve the problems from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any book that will teach us how to translate OOP constructs into Functional ones. Just give yourself some time and you will grasp the functional idioms.

Don't try to map between OOP code and FP code. The best way to learn a language (spoken language) is to immerse yourself in it and think of it. The same goes for programming languages.

Three years ago I started learning Clojure. At that time, I don't even know what is Lisp and what are functional programming languages. I said: Huh? really what is that? Can I do something useful with Lisp?  I read a lot, studied a lot and even better, I got a job in Clojure!

Now programming in functional languages feels natural to me, it makes sense. Programming in data structures and functions are all of what I need. Simplicity!

One thing to keep in mind that functional programming languages aren't difficult by default and OOP languages aren't easy by default.

Comment: Yes, I suppose learning any new paradigm involves a lot of wandering around. My concern is that Clojure's ties to Java create a temptation to write OOP code in functional clothing. I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I've not read this book, but it sounds like quite a good fit for what you're looking for (and I'm very happy with the other Pragmatic Bookshelf books I've read)

[**Functional Programming Patterns In Scala And Clojure**](http://pragprog.com/book/mbfpp/functional-programming-patterns-in-scala-and-clojure)

From the blurb:

> By using both the statically typed, type-inferred Scala and the dynamically typed, modern Lisp Clojure, you’ll gain a broad understanding of functional programming.
>   For each pattern, you’ll first see the traditional object-oriented solution, and then dig into the functional replacements in both Scala and Clojure.

Re: your piano question, you might find core.async and David Nolen's blog posts on UI design with core.async (specifically http://swannodette.github.io/2013/07/31/extracting-processes/) interesting.

In the blog post, he proposes that a user interface (and by extension, a piano), consists of 3 elements - event stream processing, event stream co-ordination and interface representation. And he shows that these are a much more powerful abstraction than the typical OOP Model View Controller. All pretty new though (I don't think core.async is even officially released yet). But if you're looking for the idiomatic Clojure way to model a piano, I think that it may well be along those lines...

Comment: For now, Nolen's post is over my head, but I'll come back to it eventually. And thanks for the book suggestion.